# How to convert a Spark Dataframe to JSONObject

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My goal is to convert a DataFrame to a valid JSONArray of JSONObject.

I'm currently using:

```
val res = df.toJSON.collect()
```

But I'm getting an Array[String] - array of JSON-escaped strings, i.e:

```
["{\"url\":\"http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_action.asp?user=123\",\"subnet\":\"32.2.208.1\",\"country\":\"\",\"status_code\":\"200\"}"]
```

I'm looking for a way to convert those strings into actual JSONObjects, I found a few solution which suggested to [find and replace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225414/how-to-let-spark-parse-a-json-escaped-string-field-as-a-json-object-to-infer-the), but I'm looking for something cleaner.

I tried to convert each string to a JSONObject using org.json library, but obviously it's not a Serializable Object.

Any suggestion? any fast Scala JSON library that can work?

Or how in general is it suggested to work with the toJSON method.

**Update**

This is a bit wasteful, but this option works for me:

```
 val res = df.toJSON.map(new JSONObject(_).toString).collect()
```

Since JSONObject is not serializable - I can use its toString to get a valid JSON format.

If you still have any suggestion on how I can improve it - please let me know.

Comment: can you update with sample data of your dataframe?

Comment: I don't get these quotes escaped when I use `toJSON`. I'm using Spark 1.6.

Comment: @philantrovert, that's odd, we use Spark 1.6.1. all the questions I saw online on this issue, stated that the format is the same.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, sorry but I can't provide the dataframe structure, this is  not my private code. however I can say that it has 2 nested fields if that helps.

I know I can pull the schema from the dataframe, is there anyway I can use that schema to write a JSONObject?

Comment: @LiranBo org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject is a Serializable indeed.

Comment: @LiranBo I'm facing the exact same problem, could you please share if you could find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
I will show how dataframe converted into Json object list in spark.
I/P: Dataframe
O/P Json : [{ "id":"111","Loc":"Pune"},{"id":"2222","Loc":"Mumbai"}]
Sol:-> 
1] Create  Person POJO having id and loc fields.
2] Suppose dataframe named 'myDF'
3] myDF.collect.foreach { record =>
 val recMap = record.getValuesMap(myDF.columns).toMap[Any, Any]
 val person =new Person
 person.setLoc(recMap("LOC"))
 jsonList.append(person) //List of Person obj
}
val gson = new Gson //GSON lib
jsonStr = gson.toJson(jsonList.asJava)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [spray-json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) to parse the string to a case class:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
case class Data(url: String, subnet: String, country: String, status_code: String)
implicit val dataFormat = jsonFormat4(Data)
val source = Array("{\"url\":\"http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_action.asp?user=123\",\"subnet\":\"32.2.208.1\",\"country\":\"\",\"status_code\":\"200\"}")
val data = source(0).parseJson.convertTo[Data]
```

Comment: I also considered the option to use case classes, but there are over 80 nested fields. So it would be pretty complex to create one. I was hoping to use the dataframe schema somehow instead.

Comment: If you just want to get some data out from the JSON, you'd only need to define the case class hierarchy for the bits that you need. eg the above would work with `case class Data(url: String, subnet: String)`, too.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, but I need almost the entire structure. I do use case classes in some inner UDFs to manipulate some of the data. but the result should include almost everything.

Comment: this is also why I preferred to use spark toJSON function instead of providing my own writer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataframeWriter class.

```
df.write.json(path)
```

This may create multiple part files if the output file has a number of records/partitions. You can then write a simple merge utility to combine part files in hdfs/local file system.

In case, output is a small file - you can use coalesce()

```
df.coalesce(1).write.json(path)
```

You can then read it back into a DF.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but performance is a serious issue here. I can't write the data to files and than read them again.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. collect data frame - you will get `Array[Row]`
2. map every row folding it to `Map[String,Any]` - the result will by `Array[Map[String,Any]]`
3. serialize to JSON

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val dataFrame = (1 to 10)
  .map(i => ("value" + i, i))
  .toDF("name", "value")

val maps = dataFrame
  .collect
  .map(
    row => dataFrame
      .columns
      .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Any])
      (
        (acc, item) => acc + (item -> row.getAs[Any](item))
      )
  )

val json = Serialization.write(maps)

println(json)
```