# How to JSON-escape a String field in Spark dataFrame with new column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to write a new column with JSON format through DataFrame. I tried several approaches but it's writing the data as JSON-escaped String field.
Currently its writing as
`{"test":{"id":1,"name":"name","problem_field": "{\"x\":100,\"y\":200}"}}`

Instead I want it to be as 
`{"test":{"id":1,"name":"name","problem_field": {"x":100,"y":200}}}`

`problem_field` is a new column that is being created based on the values read from other fields as:

```
val dataFrame = oldDF.withColumn("problem_field", s)
```

I have tried the following approaches

1. `dataFrame.write.json(<<outputPath>>)`
2. `dataFrame.toJSON.map(value => value.replace("\\", "").replace("{\"value\":\"", "").replace("}\"}", "}")).write.json(<<outputPath>>)`

Tried converting to `DataSet` as well but no luck. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

I have already tried the logic mentioned here: [How to let Spark parse a JSON-escaped String field as a JSON Object to infer the proper structure in DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225414/how-to-let-spark-parse-a-json-escaped-string-field-as-a-json-object-to-infer-the)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your example data has an extraneous comma after  `"y\":200` which will prevent it from being parsed as it is not valid JSON.

From there, you can use `from_json` to parse the field, assuming you know the schema. In this example, I'm parsing the field separately to first get the schema:

```
scala> val json = spark.read.json(Seq("""{"test":{"id":1,"name":"name","problem_field": "{\"x\":100,\"y\":200}"}}""").toDS)
json: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [test: struct<id: bigint, name: string ... 1 more field>]

scala> json.printSchema
root
 |-- test: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- problem_field: string (nullable = true)


scala> val problem_field = spark.read.json(json.select($"test.problem_field").map{
case org.apache.spark.sql.Row(x : String) => x
})
problem_field: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: bigint, y: bigint]          

scala> problem_field.printSchema
root
 |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |-- y: long (nullable = true)

scala> val fixed = json.withColumn("test", struct($"test.id", $"test.name", from_json($"test.problem_field", problem_field.schema).as("problem_field")))
fixed: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [test: struct<id: bigint, name: string ... 1 more field>]

scala> fixed.printSchema
root
 |-- test: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- problem_field: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
```

If the schema of `problem_field`s contents is inconsistent between rows, this solution will still work but may not be an optimal way of handling things, as it will produce a sparse Dataframe where each row contains every field encountered in `problem_field`. For example:

```
scala> val json = spark.read.json(Seq("""{"test":{"id":1,"name":"name","problem_field": "{\"x\":100,\"y\":200}"}}""", """{"test":{"id":1,"name":"name","problem_field": "{\"a\":10,\"b\":20}"}}""").toDS)
json: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [test: struct<id: bigint, name: string ... 1 more field>]

scala> val problem_field = spark.read.json(json.select($"test.problem_field").map{case org.apache.spark.sql.Row(x : String) => x})
problem_field: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: bigint, b: bigint ... 2 more fields]

scala> problem_field.printSchema
root
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |-- y: long (nullable = true)

scala> val fixed = json.withColumn("test", struct($"test.id", $"test.name", from_json($"test.problem_field", problem_field.schema).as("problem_field")))
fixed: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [test: struct<id: bigint, name: string ... 1 more field>]

scala> fixed.printSchema
root
 |-- test: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- problem_field: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)

scala> fixed.select($"test.problem_field.*").show
+----+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   x|   y|
+----+----+----+----+
|null|null| 100| 200|
|  10|  20|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Over the course of hundreds, thousands, or millions of rows, you can see how this would present a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Charlie, the extra comma  after  "y\":200 was a typo and it can be ignored. Coming to the solution, in my case the no. of fields in the problem_field is not fixed. I am creating this field dynamically and each record will have different number of fields. How can that be handled? Thanks.

Comment: If that's the case, there's no good solution - if the JSON in `problem_field` is arbitrary and inconsistent, then your dataframe would be too. You're better off keeping it as a string and extracting individual fields on an ad-hoc basis using `get_json_object`, or addressing the data modeling problems that got you to this point.

Comment: I've edited my solution to illustrate that it will work for the case that you've described, but may not be the best way of dealing with your issue.

Comment: OK, will check that. Thanks.