# convert a column with json value to a data frame using scala spark

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, normalization

I found several helpful answers but that were all converting son file to df, in my case, I have a df with columns with son in them, like this:

**s-timestamp**: 2019-10-10

**content**: {"META":{"testA":"1","TABLENAME":"some_table_name"},"PINACOLADA":{"sampleID":"0","itemInserted":"2019-10-10","sampleType":"BASE",}"

I need to normalize the content column, how can I do that.

Comment: What do you mean with normalization? You need to extract some columns from the json column into the initial df maybe?

Comment: probably similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58037893/read-external-json-file-into-rdd-and-extract-specific-values-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! There are a few ways of dealing with JSON strings in Spark DF columns. You can use functions like `get_json_object` to extract specific fields from your JSON or `from_json` to transform the field into a `StructType` with a given schema. Another option is to use `spark.read.json` to parse and create a separate dataframe from the column's contents. Have a look at my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56603229/5568365) and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll have same problem as the solution post, my data may be inconsistent. I am going to experiment using your approach. Thanks so much.